# iMac stuck upgrading to macOS High Sierra

Tags: imac, high-sierra, upgrade

I am upgrading my iMac to macOS High Sierra, however it has been stuck at 28 seconds remaining for a long time now. Is there any way to resume setup without losing downloaded files?

The install log is as follows, along with the upgrade screenshot:

```
Apr  5 01:11:02 iMac InstallAssistant[10020]: Hardware: iMac14,1 @ 2.70 GHz (x 4), 8192 MB RAM
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Apr  5 07:56:11 iMac softwareupdated[398]: BackgroundActions: Automatic checking disabled
Apr  5 07:56:11 iMac softwareupdated[398]: BackgroundActivity: Finished Background Check Activity
Apr  5 07:56:11 iMac softwareupdate_notify_agent[401]: Handling notification event: UpdatesAvailable
Apr  5 07:56:11 iMac softwareupdate_notify_agent[401]: AssertionMgr: Take com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-UpdatesAvailable assertion with type BackgroundTask for pid 401, id 0x869A
Apr  5 07:56:11 iMac softwareupdate_notify_agent[401]: Waiting 60 seconds before sending the notification to App Store
Apr  5 07:57:11 iMac softwareupdate_notify_agent[401]: Notifying with params: {
        AutomaticCheckDisabled = 1;
        SoftwareUpdateCount = 2;
        SoftwareUpdatesAvailable = 1;
        UpdatesRequireRestart = 1;
    }
Apr  5 07:57:11 iMac softwareupdate_notify_agent[401]: appstoreupdateagent notified
Apr  5 07:57:11 iMac softwareupdate_notify_agent[401]: AssertionMgr: Cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-UpdatesAvailable assertion for pid 401, id 0x869A
Apr  5 09:24:17 iMac osinstallersetupd[10026]: Is solid state disk returned: -69808
Apr  5 09:24:17 iMac osinstallersetupd[10026]: isConvertableToAPFS: was called on a APFS disk.
Apr  5 09:24:17 iMac osinstallersetupd[10026]: Target is not convertible to APFS: This volume is not formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, which iMac are you using, and about how long has it been stuck at 28 seconds remaining? Have you tried to click Cancel?

Comment: iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013), 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3it has been stuck since about 7 hours, Yes I tried to cancel but didn't do that, I don't want to lose downloaded data if not I should redownload all again.